# How to stop auto logout adminpanel in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to stop auto logout my adminpanel. i also changed .env file and  add "SESSION_LIFETIME" field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set long-time session. To do this you have to edit `config/session.php` and set `lifetime` to value you need in minutes. For example:

```
'lifetime' => 525600, // one year
```

After edit you have to clear config cache with command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

**Edit:-** you can add this `constant` in `.env` file as well as like `SESSION_LIFETIME` but after don't forget to use this command `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: It's a good idea to change the session lifetime from .env file `SESSION_LIFETIME`, instead of changing directly in session.php config file.